# how to generate urdf.rviz file

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am curious about how to generate the **urdf.rviz file**, since I have seen a lot of tutorials using urdf.rviz file when **loading urdf to rviz**.

It just happened but they did not explain how we can **derive a urdf.rviz file by our own**, without which we can not use below code in launch file:

```
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
```

Instead, I have to  rosrun a rviz instance and add a robotmodel mannually

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251387/how-to-generate-urdf.rviz-file/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

urdf.rviz is just an configuration file that is not generated automatically. The easiest way to generate these files is to open RVIZ, add some panels and save the resulting configuration. It's only about personal preferences so that there isn't really a way to generate or derive .rviz files.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-06**:
Thanks for your answer, it helps.
I thought the rviz config file is related to the urdf file, so I wanted to find a way to generate it and use it in launch file.
Now I know it really does not matter but a config for rviz .
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start with the following example:

```
<robot name="robot">

<link name="base_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="100" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="100" iyz="0" izz="100" />
    <origin/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.125" />
    <geometry>
        <box size=".50 .50 .250" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="red">
      <color rgba="1 0.47 0.13 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>

  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.125" />
    <geometry>
      <box size=".50 .250 .50" />
    </geometry>
    <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
  </collision>
</link>
```

save this as robot_model.xml

use following launch file with `robot_state_publisher`

```
<launch>
        <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find package_name)/robot_model.xml" />
        <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />           
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-03**:
+1 for making the effort to put together an example, but the OP asks how to 'generate' an RViz configuration file. Not a urdf file.